# How to get adapter item position from AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

```
String[] idArray = {"1","2","3","4"};

String[] nameArray = {"Abraham","Abhi","John","Joseph"};


final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterTextView = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,nameArray);

etItemName.setAdapter(adapterTextView);

etItemName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

        String id = idArray[position];

    }
});
```

This is my code. In this, when I type "Jo", **John** and **Jospeh** are populating on `AutoCompleteTextView` and when I selected **John** I get `String id` as **0**. But actually I need is **2**. So how can I get **2** instead of **0**?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside the onItemClick, after writing "Jo" you will see ((ListView) adapterView).getAdapter().getCount() = 2.  There are 2 items inside the adapter, "John" and "Joseph". @n9153's solution could work for you.

Comment: @Lev I know that. Because its loading strings starting with "JO". I want to get actual position of which item is selected from adapter array that is nameArray.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the perfect solution but you can take it as the last option:

When you pass the selected string just loop through your nameArray to find its position:

```
 int position=-1;
    for(int i=0;i<nameArray.length;i++){
    if(selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase(nameArray[i])){
        position=i;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

@Shaheer Palollathil n9153's suggestion would work. I'm just changing his answer according to your code.

```
AutoCompleteTextView t;
    t.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int pos = -1;
            for(int i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++){
                if(((AutoCompleteTextView)view).getText().toString().equals(nameArray[position]))
                    pos = position;
                    break;
            }
            String id = idArray[pos]; // should be your desired number
        }
    });
```